# media query and not

Tags: less, media-queries

I have the following less code:

```
@mobile: ~'screen and (max-width: 480px)';
```

Then I use it as follows:

```
@media @mobile {  
  // some code
}
```

It works fine but I would like to also use "not" like:

```
@media not @mobile {  
  // some code
}
```

But I get the error

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input
```

in the "not" part.

Is it possible to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

Define the width of a mobile device:

```
@mobileWidth: 480px;
```

Then anything larger is a non-mobile device:

```
@notmobileWidth: @mobileWidth + 1px;
```

Create LESS variables for both mobile and notmobile:

```
@mobile: ~'screen and (max-width: @{mobileWidth})';
@notmobile: ~'screen and (min-width: @{notmobileWidth})';
```

And then use those in your media queries:

```
@media @mobile {
  // some mobile code
}

@media @notmobile {
  // some not-mobile code
}
```